# Slow Query Performance During Process Of SSAS Tabular

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssas-tabular

As part of My SSAS Tabular Process Script Task in a SSIS Package, I read all new rows from the database and insert them to Tabular database using Process Add. The process works fine but for the duration of the Process Add, user queries to my Tabular model becomes very slow. 
Is there a way to prevent the impact of Process Add on user queries? Users need near real time queries.

I am using SQL Server 2012 SP2.

Thanks

Comment: Roughly how many rows do you add every time you run the SSIS package?

Comment: There are about 10 tables in my database and depending on the table and activity during the day, I will Process Add between zero and 10,000 rows every hour.